# VBA Help Solve Code for copying, filter, paste into rows based on condition

Tags: excel, vba

**Goal:** When there is a number in Worksheet RP, column W i.e. not blank, that particular row's data needs to be copied to the next empty row of worksheet Calc Data. However, the data in question is not in order, i.e. row A =/= ACC# Parish for the Worksheet RP.

Thus needs to follow = if column W not blank, then copy column B(rows not blank), column D(rows not blank), column A(rows not blank), etc into Worksheet Calc at next empty row, columns A - P as applicable.

Worksheet collects data in the below format
[image: Calc Data, copying into last empty row here]

Worksheet with data that needs to be manipulated 
[image: Column in question]

**Help Solve Code:** I have sorta started my code but I am stuck on how to continue, or even if I am on the right track! The list columns start to be out of range, and I am not sure how to get it to filter for non-blank ranges only, or how to copy the columns for the particular data into the end rows (A - Q) in a particular order!

```
Dim RPDataTbl As ListObject
Dim parishCol As ListColumn, LossRentcol As ListColumn, parishcodeCol As ListColumn, buildnoCol As ListColumn, insuredassCol As ListColumn, crestaCol As ListColumn, basiscoverCol As ListColumn

Dim copyRng As Range

Set RPDataTbl = Sheets("Risk Partner Data").ListObjects("RPdata")
With RPDataTbl
    Set parishCol = .ListColumns("Parish")
    Set LossRentcol = .ListColumns("Loss of Income or Rent")
    Set parishcodeCol = .ListColumns("Parish Code")
    Set crestaCol = .ListColumns("Cresta")
    Set basiscoverCol = .ListColumns("Basis of Cover")

    .Range.AutoFilter Field:=LossRentcol.Index, Criteria1:= <not blank?>
End With

On Error Resume Next
Set copyRng = parishCol.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not copyRng Is Nothing Then
    copyRng.Copy

    With Sheets("Calc Data")
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If
```

Thank you to all in advance!